# Ignore sonarqube rule 'Subclasses that add fields should override "equals"' for all subclasses?

Tags: java, sonarqube

My entities (using Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA and Hibernate) are all extending from an `AbstractEntity` class I have defined. This class implements `equals()` and `hashcode()` in such a way that subclasses do not need to handle this anymore.

SonarQube will now report a violation about:

> Subclasses that add fields should override "equals"

for each subclass.

I can suppress this by adding `@SuppressWarnings("squid:S2160")` on each subclass. But I was wondering if there was a way to state to SonarQube: this rule should not trigger if a class is a subclass of `AbstractEntity` so I don't need to repeat the supression of the warning in each subclass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you make the methods `final`, then SonarQube will not trigger the warning anymore.